# Dealing with subsets of data using csv.DictReader

Tags: python, csv

I'm parsing a big CSV file using `csv.DictReader`.

```py
quotes=open( "file.csv", "rb" )
csvReader= csv.DictReader( quotes )
```

Then for each row I'm converting the time value in the CSV in datetime using this :

```py
for data in csvReader:
    year = int(data["Date"].split("-")[2])
    month = strptime(data["Date"].split("-")[1],'%b').tm_mon
    day = int(data["Date"].split("-")[0])
    hour = int(data["Time"].split(":")[0])
    minute = int(data["Time"].split(":")[1])
       
    bars = datetime.datetime(year,month,day,hour,minute)
```

Now I would like to perform actions only on the rows of the **same day**. Would it be possible to do it in the same for loop or should I maybe save the data out per day and then perform actions? What would be an efficient way of baking the parsing?

Comment: FYI, all that conversion can just be `bars = datetime.datetime.strptime(data['Date']+data['Time'],'%d-%b-%Y%H:%M')` (might need adjustments to format, since no sample provided.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As jogojapan has pointed out, it is important to know whether we can assume that the CSV file is sorted by date. If it is, then you could use [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to simplify your code. For example, the for loop in this code iterates over the data one day at time:

```
import csv
import datetime
import itertools

with open("file.csv", "rb") as quotes:
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(quotes)

    lmb = lambda d: datetime.datetime.strptime(d["Date"], "%d-%b-%Y").date()
    for k, g in itertools.groupby(csvReader, key = lmb):
        # do stuff per day
        counts = (int(data["Count"]) for data in g)
        print "On {0} the total count was {1}".format(k, sum(counts))
```

I created a test "file.csv" containing the following data:

```
Date,Time,Count
1-Apr-2012,13:23,10
2-Apr-2012,10:57,5
2-Apr-2012,11:38,23
2-Apr-2012,15:10,1
3-Apr-2012,17:47,123
3-Apr-2012,18:21,8
```

and when I ran the above code I got the following results:

```
On 2012-04-01 the total count was 10
On 2012-04-02 the total count was 29
On 2012-04-03 the total count was 131
```

But remember that this will only work if the data in "file.csv" is sorted by date.

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have mentioned that the csv file was sorted

Answer (score 2):

**If (for some reason) you can assume** that the input rows are *already sorted by date*, you could put them into a local container one by one as long as the date of any new row is the same as the previous one:

```
same_date_rows = []
prev_date      = None
for data in csvReader:
  # ... your existing code
  bars = datetime.datetime(year,month,day,hour,minute)

  if bars == prev_date:
    same_date_rows.append(data)
  else:
    # New date. We process all rows collected so far
    do_something(same_date_rows)
    # Then we start a new collection for the new date
    same_date_rows = [date]

  # Remember the date of the current row
  prev_date = bars

# Finally, process the final group of rows
do_something(same_date_rows)
```

**But if you cannot make that assumption**, you will have to

- **Either:** Put the rows in a long list, sort that by date, and then apply an algorithm like the above to the sorted list
- **Or:** Put the rows in a `dictionary`, using the date as key, and a list of rows as value for each key. Then you can iterate through the keys of that dictionary to get access to all rows that share a date.

The second of these two approaches is a little more space-consuming, but it may allow you do to some of the date-specific processing in the main loop, because whenever you receive a new row for an already-existing date, you could apply some of the date-specific processing right away, possibly avoiding the need to actually store all date-specific rows explicitly. Whether that is possible depends on what kind of processing you apply to the rows.

Comment: a third solution would be to put the data in a sqlite database

Answer (score 1):

If you are not going for space efficeny, an elegant solution would be to create a dictionary where the key is your day, and the value is a list object, where all the information for each day is stored. Later you can do whatever operations you want based on per day.

For example

```
d = {} #Initialize emptry dictionry 
for data in csvReader:
Day = int(data["Date"].split("-")[0])
   try:
       d[Day].append('Some_Val')
   except KeyError:
       d[Day] = ['Some_val']
```

This will either modify or create a new list object for each day. This is later easily accessible either by iterating over the dictionary or simply referring to the day as a key.

For example:

```
d[Some_Day]
```

will give you simply a list object with all the information you have stored. Given the linear lookup time of a dictionary, it should be quite efficent in terms of time.

Comment: Although this idea was already part of the previous answer, +1 for clarity and detail. One remark: Although a dictionary lookup can indeed be linear in the worst case, that wouldn't really be very efficient. I think you want to say the "_near-constant_ lookup time of a dictionary".

Comment: Yes, I intended to say a O(1), but only to satisfy the worst case I went for O(n). Thanks for stating it clearly.